# Prove that $H = \{1, −1, i, −i\}$ is a subgroup of the group of nonzero complex number under multiplication.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Prove that $H = \{1, −1, i, −i\}$ is a subgroup of the group of nonzero complex number under multiplication.

Since $H$ is finite it is enough to show that if $H$ is closed under multiplication then it is a subgroup of $G$. I can easily verify Given any elements of $H$ they are closed. Or that multiplication of $\pm1$ and $\pm i$ are by definition $\pm 1$ or $\pm i$

Is there a better way to say this?

Also is there some property that uniquely determines this subgroup $H$ that could help me prove this

Comment: Just Write the multiplication table.

Comment: Your argument is correct. @rschweib 's answer is a little cleverer and more informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is a group, and it has an element $i$.

This element $i$ generates a cyclic subgroup

$\langle i\rangle=\{i, i^2,i^3,\ldots\}=\{i, -1, -i, 1\}$.

Does anything more need to be said?

Looking at it as a cyclic subgroup at least makes it obvious it's closed under multiplication and inverses.

Answer (score 3):

> Or that multiplication of $\pm1$ and $\pm i$ are by definition $\pm 1$ or $\pm i$

Technically, you also need to show that that and that multiplication of $\pm 1$ and $\pm 1$ is $\pm 1$ or $\pm i$, and that multiplication of $\pm i$ and $\pm i$ is $\pm 1$ or $\pm i$.

---

I don't really see an easier way to show this, however a nicer way might be to show that

$$f:(\mathbb Z_4, +)\to H\\
f(n) = i^n$$

is an isomorphism.